# Black Screen after installing "mesa" library

Tags: boot, screen, mesa

I'm using Ubuntu-12.04.

I haved installed `mesa` library using the apt-get command:

```
sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa && sudo apt-get install libosmesa6
```

And Ubuntu doesn't boot after installing the `mesa` library.

Then I reboot Ubuntu but it only shows black screen.

I didn't modify anything at Ubuntu, only installed the `mesa` graphic library.

Help me please.

Comment: how did you install mesa library?what command did you tried?

Comment: sudo apt-get install libglapi-mesa && sudo apt-get install libosmesa6

Answer (score 0):

What graphics card? If Nvidia, switch into tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1/F2), login and try

```
jockey-text --list
```

to see what drivers you have in you system. You may need to install jockey (sudo apt-get install jockey-text).

Then use the latest stable Nvidia driver (331 I guess) and start yor display manager (lightdm/gdm)

```
sudo jockey-text -e kmod:nvidia_331
sudo service lightdm start #or gdm start, depends on what you use.
```

Hope, it will help.

Answer (score 0):

- Login into virtual console(ctrl+Alt+F1)
- remove the previously installed packages,

  ```
  sudo apt-get purge libglapi-mesa && sudo apt-get purge libosmesa6
  ```
- Then restart lightdm

  ```
  sudo service lightdm restart
  ```